# How to remove element by class only if it contains an element with some specified text?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
<tr class="Action Head" data-index="1">
    <td class="Template">
        <div class="Description">
            <span class="Text Description" id="MainDescription">text</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can I remove element with class="Action Head" if span that's inside it with id="MainDescription" contains some specified text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) to select elements by their content, using a function that checks the content of the element to see if it matches your required criteria. For example:

```
//variable rowsToRemove will be an array that contains all the rows that contain
//a span with id MainDescription which contain the word 'text'

var rowsToRemove = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('.Action.Head'), function(row){
    var mainDescriptionSpan = row.querySelector('span#MainDescription');
    return (mainDescriptionSpan && mainDescriptionSpan.textContent.indexOf('text') != -1);
});

if (rowsToRemove.length) {  //if there are some row(s) that match the criteria...
    rowsToRemove.forEach(function(row){  // ... loop through all of them ...
        row.remove();  // ... and remove them.
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `querySelectorAll` to gather the whole set of elements `Action Head` then loop over those elements and for each `Action Head` element get its span element.

With that `span` element check the attribute `textContent`.

This code snippet will remove only one TR.

```js
var actions = document.querySelectorAll('.Action.Head');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(actions, function(action) {
  var span = action.querySelector('span');
  if (span.textContent === 'text') span.remove();
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Action Head" data-index="1">
      <td class="Template">
        <div class="Description">
          <span class="Text Description" id="MainDescription">text</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="Action Head" data-index="1">
      <td class="Template">
        <div class="Description">
          <span class="Text Description" id="MainDescription2">text2</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but what if there are more than one span elements in `Action Head`? How can I check the id of each of these span elements and remove it only if it is `MainDescription`?

Comment: You have created two different HTML Elements with the same `id`. That is not valid.